# get the index of counted dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to return the index of DataFrame statement, first I am loading a csv (CSV example below)

[image]

I created a code to count the number of each hour and return the max number as below

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'mylist.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

df['Start Time'] = df['Start Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

df['hour'] = df['Start Time'].dt.hour

# find the most common hour (from 0 to 23)
popular_hour = df.groupby(['hour'])['hour'].count().max()

print('Most Frequent Start Hour:', popular_hour)
```

what I am trying to do is to return the hour not the counted value, I've tried `index` as below but doesn't work

```
popular_hour = df.groupby(['hour'])['hour'].count().max().index.values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for indice of maximal value of `Series` returned by [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

*Notice: For convert to datetimes is better use parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).*

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['Start Time','End Time'])

df['hour'] = df['Start Time'].dt.hour

popular_hour = df.groupby(['hour'])['hour'].count().idxmax()
```

Another idea is use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) - there is default sorting, so first value is also maximal:

```
popular_hour = df['hour'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

working same like selecting first index:

```
popular_hour = df['hour'].value_counts().index[0]
```